# How to Get Windows NT Logged User Name in ASP.NET 3.5 in intranet application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

I have an intranet asp.net application and when a page is loaded, i want to log the IP Address, Computer Name and the Windows Account(from active directory) currently logged into the computer from which the page is being accessed.

So far, Im able to get the IP address and computer name but the windows account, am getting **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment.UserDomainName + "\" + Environment.UserName

Comment: hmm. sounds like you are not logging into a server domain?

Comment: Isn't Enviroment.UserName the username of the windows account that is HOSTING asp.net?

Comment: actaully, Environment.UserName is returning the security account under which application pool for the site is running. So if Application Pool Identity is running under Local System, Environment.UserName returns "System", if application pool identity is set to Network Service, Environment.UserName returns NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE

Comment: I am sorry I didn't read the asp.net part. Not sure how you are going to extract that ntusername info... I will google a bit comment if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

You need to make sure that your web site is set up to to sue integrated windows authentication and that anonymous access is turned off...